# minitoc problem

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, thesis, minitoc

I 'm writing my phd using  Thesis.cls But i have a problem with minitoc. The table of content of each chapter doesn't appear.
This my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind} %« Bibliographie » dans la table des matières
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}%flow chart
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx,lscape,longtable,booktabs}% long tables are split to other lines %for rotating tables
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%     definir le style d'entete
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{multirow} % muli rows (merge) in tables
\usepackage{notoccite}
%\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%redéfinition du formattage du sectioning
\usepackage{cases}%numcase
\usepackage{aeguill}%pour guillemets
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{indentfirst}%alinea
%\usepackage{color} %texte en couleur
\definecolor{usethiscolorhere}{rgb}{0.86666,0.78431,0.78431}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{these}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying
\begin{document}
%\nocite{*}
\sloppy{}
\dominitoc
\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages
\setstretch{1.5} % Line spacing of 1.3
\fancyhead{} % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage} % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\lhead{} % Clears the left side page header

\pagestyle{fancy} % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % New command to make the lines in the title page

% PDF meta-data
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\ttitle}}
\hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter*{}
\begin{flushright}
Le succès n'est pas la clé du bonheur
\end{flushright}
\newpage
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\addtotoc{Abstract} % Add the "Abstract" page entry to the Contents
\Huge \textbf{Abstract}\\
\normalsize
Hello
\clearpage % Start a new page
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Résumé
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\addtotoc{Résumé} % Add the "Abstract" page entry to the Contents
\Huge \textbf{Résumé}\\
\normalsize
Bonjour
\clearpage % Start a new page
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\pagestyle{fancy} % The page style headers have been "empty" all this time, now use the "fancy" headers as defined before to bring them back

\lhead{\emph{Table des matières}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table des matières}
\tableofcontents

\lhead{\emph{Liste des Figures}}
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{Table des figures}
\listoffigures


\lhead{\emph{Liste des Tableaux}}
\renewcommand*\listtablename{Liste des Tableaux}
\listoftables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABBREVIATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\clearpage % Start a new page

\setstretch{1.5} % Set the line spacing to 1.5, this makes the following tables easier to read
\addtotoc{Liste des acronymes}
\lhead{\emph{Liste des acronymes}} % Set the left side page header to "Abbreviations"
\listofsymbols{ll} % Include a list of Abbreviations (a table of two columns)
{
\textbf{ABC} & \textbf{A} \textbf{B} \textbf{C}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - CHAPTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapitre}
\setcounter{mtc}{9}
\input{Introduction/introduction}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - APPENDICES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}
\appendix
\backmatter
\input{Appendices/AppendixA}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Références bibliographiques}
\lhead{\emph{Références bibliographiques}} % Change the page header to say "Bibliography"
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography
\bibliography{Bibliography} % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
%\addtotoc{Liste des publications}
\lhead{\emph{Liste des publications}}
\input{Chapters/Publications}\clearpage
\end{document}
```

The chapter:

```
\chapter{premier chapitre}
\label{Chapter1}
\minitoc
```

\section{intro}
blabla \cite{rowling2005half}
Introduction:

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addstarredchapter{Introduction}
\markboth{Introduction}{}
```

Bibliography

```
 @article{rowling2005half,
 title={the Half-blood Prince},
 author={Rowling, Joanne K and Potter, Harry},
 journal={New York: Scholastic},
year={2005}
}
```

Liste des publications:

```
  \chapter*{Liste des publications}

   \label{Chapter4} 
   \lhead{Liste des publications} 

    \addstarredchapter{Liste des publications} 
     \section{Liste des conférences}
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item Rowling, J. K., & Potter, H. (1999). the Chamber of Secrets.    New York: Scholastic, 199.

    \end{enumerate}
```

Appendix

```
  \chapter*{Annexe} % Main appendix title
   \addstarredchapter{Annexe A} 
       \label{AppendixA} 
        \lhead{Annexe A. \emph{Annexe}}
```

Thank you very much (Ubuntu14.04 Texmaker 4.5)

thesis.cls

```
      \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
     \ProvidesClass{Thesis}
          [2007/22/02 v1.0
 LaTeX document class]
 \def\baseclass{book}
 \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
 \def\@checkoptions#1#2{
 \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
\@tempswafalse
 \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
\@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
\ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
\let\@this\@empty
\if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
 }
  \@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
  \PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
 \ProcessOptions\relax
 \LoadClass{\baseclass}
 \newcommand       \bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

 \newcommand\Declaration[1]{
  \btypeout{Declaration of Authorship}
  \addtotoc{Declaration of Authorship}
  \thispagestyle{plain}
   \null\vfil
  %\vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}{\huge\bf Declaration of Authorship\par}\end{center}
  %\vskip 60\p@
  {\normalsize #1}
   \vfil\vfil\null
   %\cleardoublepage
   }

   \newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}
  \def\today{\ifcase\month\or
   January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
   July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space \number\year}
  \usepackage{setspace}
  \onehalfspacing
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
   \setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
  \usepackage{vmargin}

  \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Allows the use of international characters (e.g. Umlauts)


 %  MARGINS

  \setmarginsrb  { 1.5in}  % left margin
                    { 0.6in}  % top margin
                    { 1.0in}  % right margin
                    { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                    {  20pt}  % head height
                    {0.25in}  % head sep
                    {   9pt}  % foot height
                    { 0.3in}  % foot sep
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \raggedbottom
  \setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
  \doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
  \brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
  \widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
  \clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
   \interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
  \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
 \chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space      #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}
 \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
 \renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
  def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \hbox{}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
 \newpage
 \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
 \newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
 \newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
 \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
 \theoremstyle{remark}
  \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
 \usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
  \setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
 \newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
 \newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
  \newcommand{\eref}[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}
 \newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
  \newcommand{\sref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
 \newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
 \renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
 \renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
 \renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
 \renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.85}
 \renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
   \renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.75}
  \setcounter{topnumber}{9}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
 \setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
  \setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{epstopdf}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
   \usepackage{rotating}
  \usepackage{listings}
   \usepackage{lstpatch}
    \lstset{captionpos=b,
    frame=tb,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keepspaces=true}
    \lstdefinestyle{matlab} {
    language=Matlab,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.55,0.13}\em,
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.7,0,0} }
   \usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
  bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
  colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},
   pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
  \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
    \let\\\space
 }
 \newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\thesistitle}[1]{\def\ttitle{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\examiner}[1]{\def\examname{#1}}
  \newcommand*{\degree}[1]{\def\degreename{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\authors}[1]{\def\authornames{#1}}
  \newcommand*{\addresses}[1]{\def\addressnames{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\university}[1]{\def\univname{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\UNIVERSITY}[1]{\def\UNIVNAME{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\department}[1]{\def\deptname{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\DEPARTMENT}[1]{\def\DEPTNAME{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\group}[1]{\def\groupname{#1}}
 \newcommand*{\GROUP}[1]{\def\GROUPNAME{#1}}
   \newcommand*{\faculty}[1]{\def\facname{#1}}
      \newcommand*{\FACULTY}[1]{\def\FACNAME{#1}}
     \newcommand*{\subject}[1]{\def\subjectname{#1}}
   \newcommand*{\keywords}[1]{\def\keywordnames{#1}}


    %   DOCUMENT VARIABLES
    %   Fill in the lines below to update the thesis template
    %   If you wish to cite each of the variables defined below, look at the
    %   section above for the citation command e.g. \examiner{} below is
    %   defined as \examname above so you cite it as \examname
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  \thesistitle{Thesis Title} % Your thesis title - this is used in the title and abstract
    %-------------------------------------------------  
    \supervisor{Dr. James \textsc{Smith}} % You supervisor's name - this is used in the title page
     %-------------------------------------------------   
   \examiner{} % Your examiner's name - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \examname if you want it
    %-------------------------------------------------   
   \degree{Doctor of Philosophy} % Your degree name - this is currently used in the title page and abstract
     %-------------------------------------------------   
   \authors{John \textsc{Smith}} % Your name - this is used in the title page and abstract
      %-------------------------------------------------   
    \addresses{} % Your address - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \addressnames if you want it
     %-------------------------------------------------   
    \subject{} % Your subject area - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \subjectname if you want it
      %-------------------------------------------------   
   \keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \keywordnames if you want it
      %-------------------------------------------------   
     \university{\texorpdfstring{\href{http://www.university.com} % Your university's URL
            {University Name}} % Your university's name - this is currently used in the title page
            {University Name}}
       %-------------------------------------------------   
      \UNIVERSITY{\texorpdfstring{\href{University Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your university's URL
            {UNIVERSITY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your university's name in capitals - this is currently used in the abstract page
            {UNIVERSITY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
   %-------------------------------------------------                
   \department{\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your department's URL
            {Department or School Name}} % Your department's name - used in the title page and abstract
            {Department or School Name}}
    %-------------------------------------------------                
     \DEPARTMENT{\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your department's URL
            {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your department's name in capitals - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \DEPTNAME if you want it
            {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
     %-------------------------------------------------                
    \group{\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your research group's URL
            {Research Group Name}} % Your research group's name - this is currently used in the title page 
            {Research Group Name}}
   %-------------------------------------------------                
  \GROUP{\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your research group's URL
            {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} 
            {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
   %-------------------------------------------------                
  \faculty{\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include  http://)} % Your faculty's URL
             {Faculty Name}} % Your faculty's name - this is currently used in the abstract page
            {Faculty Name}}
  %-------------------------------------------------                
   \FACULTY{\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your faculty's URL
            {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your faculty's name in capitals - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with       \FACNAME if you want it
            {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}


 % The default title page, this is not used in this    www.latextemplates.com    version            
 \renewcommand\maketitle{
 \btypeout{Title Page}
 \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
 \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
 \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
 \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{titlepage}
\let\footnotesize\small
\let\footnoterule\relax
 \let \footnote \thanks
 \setcounter{footnote}{0}
 \null\vfil
 \vskip 60\p@
 \begin{center}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  {\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
  \vfill
  {\huge \bf \@title \par}
  \vfill
  {\LARGE by \par}
  \smallskip
  {\LARGE \authornames \par}
  \vfill
  {\large A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment for the \par}
  {\large degree of \degreename \par}
  \bigskip
  \bigskip
  {\large in the \par}
  {\large \facname \par}
  {\large \deptname \par} 
  \bigskip
  \bigskip
  \bigskip
  {\Large \@date \par}
  \bigskip
\end{center}
\par
\@thanks
\vfil\null
 \end{titlepage}
 \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
\global\let\thanks\relax
\global\let\maketitle\relax
 \global\let\@thanks\@empty
 \global\let\@author\@empty
 \global\let\@date\@empty
\global\let\@title\@empty
\global\let\title\relax
\global\let\author\relax
 \global\let\date\relax
 \global\let\and\relax
 \cleardoublepage
   }

  % ABSTRACT PAGE DESIGN

\newenvironment{abstract}
 {
 \btypeout{Abstract Page}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\vfil
\begin{center}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
{\normalsize \UNIVNAME \par} % University name in capitals
\bigskip
{\huge{\textit{Abstract}} \par}
\bigskip
{\normalsize \facname \par} % Faculty name
{\normalsize \deptname \par} % Department name
\bigskip
{\normalsize \degreename\par} % Degree name
\bigskip
{\normalsize\bf \@title \par} % Thesis title
\medskip
{\normalsize by \authornames \par} % Author name
\bigskip
  \end{center}
 }

 {
 \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
 \cleardoublepage
  }
 \addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{Table of Contents}
\addtotoc{Table des matières}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
\if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\else
  \@restonecolfalse
\fi
\chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{
       \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
\@starttoc{toc}
\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
  \cleardoublepage
  }\end{spacing}
 }
 \renewcommand\listoffigures{
 \btypeout{List of Figures}
 \addtotoc{Table des Figures}
 \begin{spacing}{1}{
 \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
 \if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\else
  \@restonecolfalse
\fi
\chapter*{\listfigurename
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
          {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
\@starttoc{lof}
\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
\cleardoublepage
 }\end{spacing}
 }
 \renewcommand\listoftables{
 \btypeout{List of Tables}
\addtotoc{Liste des Tableaux}
 \begin{spacing}{1}{
\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
\if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\else
  \@restonecolfalse
\fi
\chapter*{\listtablename
  \@mkboth{
      \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
\@starttoc{lot}
\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
\cleardoublepage
 }\end{spacing}
 }
\newcommand\listsymbolname{Liste des acronymes}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofsymbols[2]{
 \btypeout{\listsymbolname}
\addtotoc{\listsymbolname}
\chapter*{\listsymbolname
  \@mkboth{
      \MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}}
  \begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
  \cleardoublepage
 }
 \newcommand\listconstants{Physical Constants}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \newcommand\listofconstants[2]{
 \btypeout{\listconstants}
 \addtotoc{\listconstants}
   \chapter*{\listconstants
  \@mkboth{
      \MakeUppercase\listconstants}{\MakeUppercase\listconstants}}
 \begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
   \cleardoublepage
    }
   \newcommand\listnomenclature{Symbols}
   \usepackage{longtable}
   \newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{
  \btypeout{\listnomenclature}
  \addtotoc{\listnomenclature}
  \chapter*{\listnomenclature
  \@mkboth{
      \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}{\MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}}
   \begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
  \cleardoublepage
  }
 \newcommand\acknowledgements[1]{
 \btypeout{Acknowledgements}
 \addtotoc{Acknowledgements}
 \thispagestyle{plain}
  \begin{center}{\huge{\textit{Acknowledgements}} \par}\end{center}
 {\normalsize #1}
  \vfil\vfil\null

 }
 \newcommand\dedicatory[1]{
 \btypeout{Dedicatory}
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \null\vfil
\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\Large \sl #1}\end{center}
\vfil\null
\cleardoublepage
 }
\renewcommand\backmatter{
\if@openright
\cleardoublepage
\else
  \clearpage
  \fi

%  \addtotoc{Références bibliographiques}
%  \renewcommand{\bibname}{Références bibliographiques}
\btypeout{\bibname}

\@mainmatterfalse}
\endinput
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are myriads of `Thesis.cls` around the world; can you point to the one you're using?

Comment: Do you have used the `\minitoc` command in the relevant chapters at all?

Comment: [cross-post](http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/minitoc-ne-fonctionne-plus-t16579.html)

Comment: @egreg i've added the thesis.cls that i'm using.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes i've called \minitoc in each chapter like in the mwe

Comment: @amandana: Of course your document is still not compilable since there are a lot of `\input` statements for files we don't have. It is not a MWE!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i've added the missing inputs. thank you

Comment: I regret to inform you that `Thesis.cls` is not a good class. You should not use it to protect your own sanity.

Comment: You cannot just remove the author statement from a file and post it online, that is not how copyright works. I recommend deleting the content and provide a proper link.

Answer (score 1):

This is known problem because of starred chapters. Here are two ways:

**1 (not recommended)** Replace `\setcounter{mtc}{9}` with `\setcounter{mtc}{6}` (well try to find the correct value)

**2** Remove `\setcounter{mtc}{9}` and redefine  `\addtotoc`

```
\renewcommand\addtotoc[1]{%
\refstepcounter{dummy}%
\addstarredchapter{#1}%  or \mtcaddchapter[#1]%
\markboth{#1}{}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but it didn't work for me I 've tried the 3 solutions. with the 2nd solution i got the \minitoc of chapter 1 in chap 2 and the one of chapter 2 in chap3 and nothing in chapter1. with the first solution mtc=11 I got nothing

Comment: with first solution try mtc=6or5... with second solution try to add `\adjustmtc` before chapter 1.

Comment: Thank you very much @touhami it worked with \setcounter{mtc}{5}

Comment: @amandana your welcome :-)